# How to set Image in Diffrent ImageView?

Tags: android, camera, imageview

I have five ImageView and five buttons and click of every button camera open for click image. Now what i want that if user click on third button and capture image then set that image  in third imageview and same for others. How can in achieve this? Below is my code.

```
public class ConDetTenthFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    //keep track of cropping intent
    final int PIC_CROP = 3;
    final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;

    Bitmap thePic;

    Uri picUri;

    public ImageView imageView1, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4, imageView5;
    public Button camera1, camera2, camera3, camera4, camera5;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.con_det_tenth_fragment, container, false);

        camera1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.camera1);
        camera2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.camera2);
        camera3 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.camera3);
        camera4 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.camera4);
        camera5 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.camera5);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView2 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView3 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageView4 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        imageView5 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);

        //Button Click Event
        camera1.setOnClickListener(this);
        camera2.setOnClickListener(this);
        camera3.setOnClickListener(this);
        camera4.setOnClickListener(this);
        camera5.setOnClickListener(this);


        return rootView;
    }

    public static ConDetTenthFragment newInstance(String text) {

        ConDetTenthFragment f = new ConDetTenthFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }

    private void performCrop() {

        try {

            //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            //indicate image type and Uri

            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            //set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            //indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            //indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
            //retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            //display an error message
            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {

            //user is returning from capturing an image using the camera
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) {

                //get the Uri for the captured image
                Uri uri = picUri;
                Log.d("picUri", uri.toString());

                //carry out the crop operation
                performCrop();

            } else if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
                //get the returned data
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                //get the cropped bitmap
                thePic = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

                //display the returned cropped image
                imageView1.setImageBitmap(thePic);



            }
        }
    }


    public void selectImage1() {
        try {
            //use standard intent to capture an image
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            String imageFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/picture.jpg";
            File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);
            picUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile); // convert path to Uri
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            //display an error message
            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.camera1:
                // code
                selectImage1();
                break;
            case R.id.camera2:
                // code
                selectImage1();
                break;
            case R.id.camera3:
                // code
                selectImage1();
                break;
            case R.id.camera4:
                // code
                selectImage1();
                break;
            case R.id.camera5:
                // code
                selectImage1();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some string or int to store which image to save in which imageview.

```
String setInImageView="1";

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.camera1:
            // code
            setInImageView="1";
            selectImage1();
            break;
        case R.id.camera2:
            // code
            setInImageView="2";
            selectImage1();
            break;
        case R.id.camera3:
            // code
            setInImageView="3";
            selectImage1();
            break;
        case R.id.camera4:
            // code
            setInImageView="4";
            selectImage1();
            break;
        case R.id.camera5:
            // code
            setInImageView="5";
            selectImage1();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And in onActivityResult,

```
 if(setInImageView.equals("1")
    imageView1.setImageBitmap(thePic);
 else if(setInImageView.equals("2")
    imageView2.setImageBitmap(thePic);
 else if(setInImageView.equals("3")
    imageView3.setImageBitmap(thePic);
 else if(setInImageView.equals("4")
    imageView4.setImageBitmap(thePic);
 else if(setInImageView.equals("5")
    imageView5.setImageBitmap(thePic);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code herepublic void onClick(View v) {
    image1=false;image2=false;.......image5=false;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.camera1:
            // code
            image1=true; ///Boolean value

            selectImage1();
            break;
        case R.id.camera2:
            // code
               image2=true; ///Boolean value
            selectImage1();
            break;
        case R.id.camera3:
            // code
             image3=true; ///Boolean value
            selectImage1();
            break;
        case R.id.camera4:
            // code
            image4=true; ///Boolean value
            selectImage1();
            break;
        case R.id.camera5:
            // code
            image5=true; ///Boolean value
            selectImage1();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

set Boolean value for each click for identified the image to set....and declare all boolean variable globally.

And check the condition when set the image like below

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {

```
        //user is returning from capturing an image using the camera
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) {

            //get the Uri for the captured image
            Uri uri = picUri;
            Log.d("picUri", uri.toString());

            //carry out the crop operation
            performCrop();

        } else if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
            //get the returned data
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            //get the cropped bitmap
            thePic = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

            //display the returned cropped image
           if(image1){ 
           imageView1.setImageBitmap(thePic);
           }
           else if(image2){
           imageView2.setImageBitmap(thePic);
           }
           //// like wise

        }
    }
```

Hope this will you...let me know if solved.